# how to cut data from a text file and save it in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help :( i have a huge .txt file with more than 1 million records and ive already saved it into a sql server table the problem is that the file cames with spaces for example

```
id: 87936756                  name: asduyiasdjk cel:8735434            bla:erwerwerwe                        sdsd:sdfsdfsdf
```

and each row cames with a different size of spaces i tried using SUBSTRING but it doesnt work because each row cames with a different size of spaces and i need to save each row in a different column of a table in SQL Server

what i did was save the hole txt file into a single column in sql server i created a table called data with only 1 row called COLUMN and it looks like this:

```
123123123        NTGAMMA GROUP  S.A - -                                   CR 43      sdfsdfsdf - 188 IN 708                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  sdfsdfsdf     23423423423      2234234                         05                            -                        *99991231*CONSTRUCCION DE EDIFICACIONES PARA USO RESIDENCIAL
```

That's only the first row of the table DATA and it has over a million rows so how can I save each part of that COLUMN in a new table like I have to save that in a table called test and it has some rows like name telephone bla bla bla

Does SQL have something like split so I could cut all those spaces and save each data in the rows I need of the table test?

Answer (score 1):

You can update your column to a string containing comma separated values, removing all the extra white spaces by doing something like this ..

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE(Column1  NVARCHAR(MAX)) 

INSERT INTO @TestTable VALUES 
('id: 87936756                  name: asduyiasdjk cel:8735434            bla:erwerwerwe                       sdsd:sdfsdfsdf')

--Abort if necessary
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TestTable WHERE Column1 LIKE '%|%') RAISERROR('Special char exists in data',16,1)

UPDATE @TestTable
SET Column1 =  replace(
                  replace(
                     replace(
                        LTrim(RTrim(Column1)), 
                     '  ',' |'),                    
                  '| ',''),                         
               '|',',')
```

which will format your data something like this ...

```
SELECT * FROM @TestTable


╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                                  Column1                                   ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ id: 87936756 ,name: asduyiasdjk cel:8735434 ,bla:erwerwerwe sdsd:sdfsdfsdf ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Then you can split that data in one column into multiple columns

<kbd>[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)</kbd> for more information.

Comment: Preface that with `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TestTable WHERE Column1 LIKE '%|%') RAISERROR('Special char exists in data',16,1)`

Comment: @Anon very good suggestion indeed feel free to update/edit my answer I dont mind I am on phone now :S cant see a darn thing on this tiny screen